# Communicating Between two Components in Angular Using @Output and EventEmitter

Tags: angular, events, angularjs-directive, output, angular-event-emitter

Good day, Please i am new to Angular and i am working on an e-commerce cart and checkout page using Angular 9,
I would like to pass/communicate the quantity of each product entered in the input tag of the Cart Component to the Checkout page.
I have tried other method but Im stuck and the @Output method doesnt seem to work.
Below are my codes
Cart.Component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit,EventEmitter, Output,Input} from '@angular/core';
 @Input() quantities = [];
@Output() quantityChange = new EventEmitter();

 changeQuantity(quantities){
  this.quantityChange.emit(quantities);
 }

checkout() {
   
    this.quantityChange.emit ();
}
```

Checkout.component.html

```
Qty: {{quantities}}
    <app-cart (quantityChange)="ChangeQuantity($event)"></app-cart>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. incomplete code has been provided.

Comment: Please provide complete associated code of two components with their html and ts.

Answer (score 0):

In Cart.Component.ts :

```
checkout() {
    this.quantityChange.emit (quantities);
}
```

In Checkout.component.html

```
Qty: {{quantities}}
    <app-cart (quantityChange)="ChangeQuantity($event)"></app-cart>
```

In Checkout.component.ts

```
quantities = ''; // init above    
changeQuantity(e) {
      this.quantities = e
     }
```